# Linker error when using Swift ObservableObject from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, observableobject

I am trying to use a Swift class from Objective-c (as I do for many other classes) with the following error.

> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$__TtC9FileCloud18BrowserCoordinator

The issue seems to be that this particular class conforms to the Swift protocol `ObservableObject`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objcMembers
class BrowserCoordinator: NSObject, ObservableObject
{
    //...
}
```

It properly shows up in the generated `MyProject-Swift.h` header file:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9FileCloud18BrowserCoordinator") SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(ios,introduced=13.0)
@interface BrowserCoordinator : NSObject
//...
@end
```

And builds properly when used from Objective-C:

```
BrowserCoordinator* browser = BrowserCoordinator.new;
```

But then the linker fails. Could it be an Apple bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is tested & worked demo (with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

*Swift:*

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@objcMembers
public class BrowserCoordinator: NSObject, ObservableObject
{
    public func go() {
        print(">> test")
    }
}
```

*Objective-C:*

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "TestBacktoObjC-Swift.h"

@interface MyViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BrowserCoordinator* browser = BrowserCoordinator.new;
    [browser go];
}

@end
```

Comment: Just tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7 - works fine.